# can a PHP file injected by JQuery load() into a DIV find out anything about this DIV?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Suppose I go

```
$( '#' + subform_id ) .load( "subform.php" );
```

where '#' + subform_id is the ID of a DIV
... is there any way the PHP in subform.php can find out, within its PHP code, the identity of the DIV? (e.g. using its own JS code <script> section)

Or otherwise refer to it by some mechanism without knowing its ID? (e.g. to use JQ's append())

Obviously I could pass the subform_id as a param of the data object (2nd param of load()).  But I'm just wondering...

***later***

followed up on what I *thought* Victor2748 was suggesting... but in fact it was the ID of a <SCRIPT> block in the injected file which I used to gain access to the existing JS DOM.

Victor2748: if you read this, I'm not sure how you could know the "id of the parent container of your subform.php page" without somehow passing this id as a param in the load() function's data object...

***even later***

Every comment in this thread says something intelligent!  In fact, concerning the question of specifying that this is a PHP file, I'm still trying to get my head around something: obviously it *is* possible to access the DOM when JS runs in the client. But if your *PHP code* needs to know the name of the DIV into which it's being loaded I believe you do indeed have to pass this through _POST or _GET.  I think there are many reasons why injected PHP code might need this sort of info, e.g. so it can contain code which at some point injects more PHP into the same DIV...

Although... clearly that injection code will inevitably use a JS/JQ script, so maybe that would be the appropriate time to find out what you need about where you are in the DOM.

Comment: Why would you need that? And no there is no way without passing it as param to the server side script. But you'd have better to explain your expected use case

Comment: @A.Wolff you might not need it.  But then again you don't *need* script libraries.  You might on the other hand *want* it for the opportunity of doing 000s of very powerful things in your injected PHP file

Comment: It looks like i misunderstood your expected behaviour but i'm still not sure to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: This has nothing do with php - you could just as easily load 'subform.html'

Comment: @SamDufel you're objecting to the tagging of the question, right?  OK but PHP and JS are like Laurel and Hardy, Tweedledum and Tweedledee, yin and yang, or any other pair of clowns you might mention.  Perhaps you use PHP exclusively, without using JS/JQ at all, but isn't it a tad cranky to raise an objection like this?

Comment: @mikerodent - I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest with your list of comparisons.  My point was that the php reference obscures your actual question - if JS scripts in dynamically loaded content are able to access the surrounding DOM.  Talking about `the PHP in subform.php` clouds the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use `this.parentNode` to get the parent container, and use `this.parentNode.id` to get the parent div's id.

Here is an example how your loaded block can get itself as an object/node:

```
var loadedBlock = document.getElementById("nameOfYourDownloadedParentContainer")
```

Then you can use `loadedBlock.parentNode` to get its parent element, then you can get any parameter from it, to identify the element/div.

---

***Update:***

First you need to get the node of the current executing `<script>` tag:

```
var arrScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var currentScriptTag = arrScripts[arrScripts.length - 1];
```

Then, to get the parent of the script tag, use: `currentScriptTag.parentNode`

(I did not test it yet, please tell me if it helped)

Comment: this sounds great.  When you say "get itself as an object" do you mean $( this ) ?

Comment: @mikerodent No, I mean not the JQuery object, but the raw javascript element object. There are multiple ways to do this, I will give you some examples in a sec...

Comment: Apologies! I'm struggling a bit with what you mean by "nameOfYourDownloadedParentContainer"!  Where can I obtain this value from?  Or is this an ID value you give to your <script> section?

Comment: @mikerodent just the id of the parent container of your `subform.php` page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72938/discussion-between-victor2748-and-mike-rodent).

Answer (score -1):

I think so... if you have a script tag in subform.php and the file has the following HTML: Submit form, you should be able to:

```
var subformId = $('#mydiv').parent().id;
```

It would work because the script tag executes when the PHP file is included. Put the script tag at the end of subform.php to be sure.

Comment: thanks... if I understand you, this seems to be more or less what I did in the end: <script id="xxx" ... then, within that self-same <script> block, do var item = document.getElementById( "xxx" );

Comment: Yes. I don't see how imcluding a PHP page is any different from a static HTML file from the JavaScripts point of view. A script block further down the HTML document than the element you wanna access should always work. It's only when the DOM element you want to access is created after the JS is trying to access it you ran into problems.